# Need correct preg_match in php

Tags: php, preg-match

I have a preg_match expression like below,

```
$is = 'rest("docs/lasit_uct/iii_a_3_a_1_r.php?hostimage=&hostvista=")';
preg_match('/docs\/*.[^.php]*/', $is, $match);
```

`result is => XXXX/YYYYY/hello_a_13_a_12_r`

But the when i pass other argument like below,

```
$is = 'rest("docs/lasit_uct/iii_a_3_a_1_i.php?hostimage=&hostvista=")';
preg_match('/docs\/*.[^.php]*/', $is, $match);
```

`result is => XXXX/YYYYY/hello_a_13_a_12_`

the last character 'h' is missing. Why is that?. I faced the same issue for when I pass character 'p' also. what is the change I need to do in the expression for getting h also.

I tried the below codes for to get correct output.. but no luck.

```
preg_match('/(docs\/.?).php/', $onClickLink, $match);
```

and

```
preg_match('/docs\/.+\((.+)(?=.php)/', $onClickLink, $match);
```

Please advice on this

Comment: Because `[^.php]` matches a char other than `.`, `p`, and **`h`**. What was your intention? BTW, it looks like you did not post the right code, the example strings do not match at all

Comment: It doesn't match anything because you haven't `docs` in your strings. Please, show the real code.

Comment: @WiktorStribiżew I want the result i mentioned above (XXXX/YYYYY/hello_a_13_a_12_h or XXXX/YYYYY/hello_a_13_a_12_p) when i passed the param in preg_match

Comment: @Toto sorry. please see now .. question is updated

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Finally i found an expression for to get correct output for my input arguments,

```
preg_match('/(docs.+)(?=.php)/', $input_string, $match);
```

thanks for your replies. above expression returns expected output all the time.

Answer (score 0):

Use the following regex pattern:

```
$re = '/docs\/.+\((.+)(?=.php)/';
preg_match($re, 'docs/test(XXXX/YYYYY/hello_a_13_a_12_h.php?t1=23&t2=45', $match);
print_r($match[1]);
```

The output:

```
XXXX/YYYYY/hello_a_13_a_12_h
```

---

`(.+)(?=.php)` - matches character sequence `(.+)` which is followed by `.php`(ensured by lookahead positive assertion `(?=.php)`)

Comment: Please alter the code without 'test'. because some of the arguments that text vary.

Comment: @RavichandranJothi, why do you change you input conditions all the time? That's not quite good. Besides, my approach also works on your new input string

Comment: Sorry for the late reply. Please see my updated question. when i used your code i got empty response.